# How can I capture the output of Perl string eval?

Tags: perl, eval, stdout, capture

I have a piece of code that is formed through string processing and I am trying to run an eval to capture the output of the code into another string. The piece of code is formed some steps itself, which means it's not in body of Perl program in one piece. This is why I am using eval.

I tried using `Tiny::Capture` without `capture`, `capture_merged`, `capture_stdout` and also `Safe` with `Safe->new->reval()`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_merged';

# $num_loops is defined inside main code body.
my $num_loops = 10;

#In reality, new code is formed through a series of steps.
my $new_code = "foreach \$idx (0..\$num_loops-1) {print \"I am at iteration number \$idx\n\";}";

my $out = capture_merged {eval $new_code;};
print $out;
```

I'm using Perl 5.30.

The piece of code above isn't printing anything out. Neither does it print any error in log. I have given intermediate prints in original code to make sure the string thrown into eval has real code, so that's not an issue.

What is the issue in the code above?

Comment: You aren't escaping the double-quotes inside `$new_code` nor the `$`s

Comment: @jhnc, I just did. In reality $new_code wasn't assigned in one shot like mentioned here. So I missed adding escape before inner double-quotes.

Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: why are you doing `eval {$new_code}`  instead of `eval $new_code` ?

Comment: apologies. It is getting called as "eval $newcode" in the original code. I just double checked. Somehow had a mistake here in the Stackoverflow example code. 

I just checked - this code is syntax clean now and doesn't print anything out as well.

Do you see any obvious issues here...?

Comment: `foreach $idx` fails with `use strict`

Comment: Okay, I actually don't get that out. The program executes silently but nothing is stored in $out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236465/discussion-between-ad891-and-jhnc).

Comment: Check `$@` after all `eval` calls.

Comment: Is there any rationale why you have chosen to utilize `eval()` for your situation? Why not form a string with __sub__ and assign it to function ref and then execute subroutine which will return a string with result you want?

Comment: Documentation states: In both forms, the value returned is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the mini-program; a return statement may also be used, just as with subroutines. [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to give suggestions how to make poor design a working one.

Comment: Just adding `my` in `foreach my \$idx` fixes your issue.

Comment: @mob, thank you, yes there was some error and it seems both returning a string and capture_stdout works. Will debug the original code further.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is written for a reason, you should not assume return value from a function -- documentation gives details what is a return value.

Sample code how you could use `eval` for your situation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_loops = 10;
my $new_code = '
    my $r;
    $r .= "I am at iteration number $_\n" for 0..$num_loops-1;
    return $r;
';

my $out = eval $new_code;

print $out;
```

Output

```
I am at iteration number 0
I am at iteration number 1
I am at iteration number 2
I am at iteration number 3
I am at iteration number 4
I am at iteration number 5
I am at iteration number 6
I am at iteration number 7
I am at iteration number 8
I am at iteration number 9
```

Comment: thanks for the details. You are recommending to return a value directly.

Actually we saw capture_stdout was a way of getting the value from a print out, so we took the path of printing it out. We could have built a string as well.

Your example code works, thanks a bunch for this ( Got help from you twice this week!.).

However it seems the print and capture_stdout is working as well. The errors are dumped in $@ as suggested by mob. 

I will use it in the original program and try to find the error out. Then plan to build a variable instead of printing it.

Comment: @Ad891 - It would be wise to give description of the problem you try to solve in the beginning of the post and then provide sample code which used to solve/resolve the problem. It will give better understanding what OP tries to achieve and what data he/she works with. Sometimes OP choses not best (less efficient) approach to solve the problem or due lack of knowledge available perl tools/commands or lack of programming experience. At times some posts just do not make much sense -- a mind start to wobble what does OP mean in his question.

Comment: @Ad891 -- Some problems can have multiple possible solutions, sometimes a simplest one can be sufficient, but at times it is less than optimal -- a good understanding of the problem is already half of the solution. First lines of the code should be `use strict; use warnings;` -- it is a small piece of magic which will help to avoid many possible traps/pitfalls, perl parser detects many potential problems at interpretation stage.

Comment: @Ad891 -- In my personal opinion if the problem's solution can be achieved without involving external modules the more code portable. Sometimes a person who will use the code does not have luxury of these modules and `cpan` module tool has to be utilized to pull all dependencies to be installed into __home__ directory. It does require to posses knowledge, build time taken from CPU -- if it can be avoided then more __customer friendly_ the code is.

Comment: The reason for I being terse wasn't about being casual in writing or protective about overall code. It was rather to give the actual problem at hand in a concise manner, because folks wouldn't have time to go through all details when so many questions are put around in SOF. So didn't want to bore/confuse with original context.

I would keep your point in mind and give a brief context in future questions to avoid this issue. 

The script does have "use strict; use warnings;" However the errors of eval doesn't get printed on log.

Comment: We use "&> log" at end to tee everything into a log. Loads of loops, so there's 400k in log, but the error doesn't show up there. 

Now with the help of $@, I am able to see actual issue. It's simply that in some of iterations the code going into eval function doesn't have "my $i" as the loop variable. That caused it to silently drop the eval and I was wondering what's wrong with eval/capture_stdout. Then tried other things of Capture::Tiny, Capture::Tiny::Extended and so on so forth and went to a completely wrong path.

Comment: As you can figure out - as much I love this language, I don't know nook-n-corner of it. Tend to use it to solve scripting problems we have.

Yes, we can hv the simpler code and not use loads of additional CPAN modules, but being somewhere in the low/middle zone in Perl expertise, we generally bank on using more modules and fix the problem at hand. (Deadlines loom to make the script work, but people don't review code as much).

Thanks for your perspective and help. Appreciate greatly....

Comment: @Ad891 -- Google search for 'Perl bookshelf' will give you enough information to improve perl skills. May be it is not latest but still good starting point -- many problems will become easier to solve, take your time to look through available resources and mark what and where to find, return when the problem arises to review particular part.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the same as the

```
$var = `... commands ...`;
$var = qx(.. commands ..);
```

but with `commands` being perl instead of shell code, and without forking a separate process.

You can do that by localizing `STDOUT` and re-opening the local filehandle as an in-memory file.

Simple example, without any external module:

```
use strict;
sub qp(&){
    my $s;
    open local *STDOUT, '>', \$s or die "open in-memory file: $!";
    &{$_[0]};
    die $@ if $@;
    $s;
}

# Usage:
my $a = qp { eval 'print "in"' };
print "<$a>\n";
print "out\n";
# 'in' will go into the string, 'out' to the actual stdout

# Use with your example (fixed to use 'my $idx'):
my $num_loops = 10;
my $new_code = "foreach my \$idx (0..\$num_loops-1) {print \"I am at iteration number \$idx\n\";}";
my $out = qp { eval $new_code };
print $out;
```

The limitations of this are

1. that will not catch `syswrite` output -- that could be easily fixed by `tie`ing the localized `STDOUT` and implementing `PRINT`, `PRINTF` and `WRITE` to append to a string.
2. that will not catch the output from separate processes spawn by perl -- that could only be fixed by re-opening `STDOUT` to a *temporary file* (that's what `Capture::Tiny` does under the hood).

### Why your example doesn't work

In your eval'd code, you're using `foreach $idx (...)` without `$idx` being defined, and since you're within the scope of `use strict`, that errors out, and your code is not run. But you're not checking the value of `$@`, and you're not able to see that error. Change it to `foreach my $idx (...)` as I did above.